# Can OpenRefine/google refine be used for pages behind a login?

Tags: openrefine

If not, is there a comparable alternative that can?

I looked in the documentation but couldn't see anything on this subject, though it must be a common requirement.

And to be clear I mean a web-based login form, not basic http auth.

Thanks

Comment: I have to say that I've only used it against local data so I can't say, I think it was developed to support opendata standards so possibly not. Actually I've stopped using it now in favour of the Excel PowerQuery addin from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on the initial question but in regard to your followup, I'm now using the Excel PowerQuery addin. I know this is not a perfect replacement but it does do many of the same things and a lot more beside. It is actually part of Microsoft's BI strategy. I recommend 64bit Office though if processing large datasets.